# Mock Service having some dependencies unit test in jest for angular

Tags: angular, babel-jest

I have one service MetaDataService

```
@Injectable()
export class MetaDataService {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private storageService: StorageService, private platform: Platform, private router: Router) {
    console.log("MetaData Service initialized..");
  }
```

i would like to Mock this service in unit test using jest framework
i am getting following error:
Can't resolve all parameters for MetaDataService: (?, ?, ?, ?);

following is my jest config:

```
module.exports = {
  "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "html", "js", "json", "mjs"],
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/src/setupJest.ts"],
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@ionic)",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@ionic/angular)",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!@ionic|ngx-socket-io/).+\\.js$",
    "<rootDir>/dist/"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "tsconfig": "<rootDir>/src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$",
      astTransformers: {
        before: [
          'jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer',
          'jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer',
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|js|mjs|html|svg)$": "babel-jest"
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    "^app/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/app/$1",
    "^assets/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/assets/$1",
    "^environments/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/environments/$1"
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    "jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes",
    "jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot",
    "jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment"
  ]
};
```

Comment: How are you mocking it? Try using  [ng-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks)

Comment: I tried ng-mocks but not worked. i am mocking with provider

Comment: Show how you mock. Also, ng-mocks never failed me so far. `providers: [MockProvider(MetaDataService)]` should work.

Comment: MockProvider(MetaDataService) work but now i am getting error     Can't resolve all parameters for AccessResourceValidatorPipe: (?).

Comment: export class AccessResourceValidatorPipe {
  constructor(private metaDataService: MetaDataService) {}

  transform(accessResource: string) {

  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments under your question, [`MockProvider(MetaDataService)`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockProvider) does the thing for `MetaDataService`.

However, it fails on `AccessResourceValidatorPipe`, because its dependencies aren't present in `TestBed`. Therefore, you need to add them in the call of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

Or, to avoid that dependency hassle, you could use [`MockBuilder`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder). It mocks all dependencies.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  return MockBuilder(
    TestingComponent,
    [
      ItsModule,

      // only if those two aren't imported in the ItsModule
      ModuleOfMetaDataService,
      ModuleOfAccessResourceValidatorPipe,
    ],
  );
});
```

Comment: I have module 
export class BreadcrumbModule {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: BreadcrumbModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, "BreadcrumbModule");
    }
  }
}

getting error Property name expected type of string but got null

Comment: does it fail in a mock? to provide a string instead of `null`, you can use [`MockInstance`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockInstance). Could you share your test, looks like there are a lot of dependencies that aren't present in the question. Or, create a min example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-npdzr2?file=src%2Ftest.spec.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2atpdq?file=src/app/example/test.component.spec.ts

Comment: export class BreadcrumbModule {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: BreadcrumbModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, "BreadcrumbModule");
    }
  }
} my test is failing due to  (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: GraphqlModule) getting error Property name expected type of string but got null i am using ngMock. when i remove parentModule property from module constructor it work fine

Comment: Hi, just recreated - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xmmghk?file=src%2Ftest.spec.ts - works well for me. Could you make it failing?